# Unable to get the proper result for the inorder traversal in binary tree, Java Datastructure

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I have wrote the code for the preorder and inorder traversal in binary tree data structure, but the outcome of the preorder traversal is correct but i am getting some error in inorder traversal, can anyone show me the fault in my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class treepractice {
static Node root = null;

static class Node{
    int data;
    Node left, right;
    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        left=right = null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] agrs){
    treepractice tree = new treepractice();
    tree.root = new Node(1);
    tree.root.left = new Node(2);
    tree.root.right = new Node(3);
    tree.root.left.left = new Node(4);
    tree.root.left.right = new Node(5);
//  root.right.left = new Node(6);

    tree.printInorder(root);
    System.out.println();
    tree.printPreorder(root);
    System.out.println();

}



private static void printPreorder(Node root) {
    if(root == null)
        return;
        System.out.print(root.data + " ");
        printPreorder(root.left);
        printPreorder(root.right);
}

private static void printInorder(Node root) {
    if(root == null)
        return;
        printPreorder(root.left);
        System.out.print(root.data + " ");
        printPreorder(root.right);
}
}
```

Comment: Requests for debugging help is not appropriate for Stack Overflow questions.  If you have a specific question about a specific feature of your code, then edit your question with those details.  Also, regardless of where you post such a questions, do not just say "some error". Always give the exact error code, error text, or detailed description of the problematical behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are calling `printPreorder` method from `printInorder`, You have to call `printInorder`**

```
private static void printInorder(Node root) {
    if (root == null)
        return;
    printInorder(root.left);
    System.out.print(root.data + " ");
    printInorder(root.right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code printInorder method should call recursively same method

```
  private static void printInorder(Node root) {
            if (root == null)
                return;
            printInorder(root.left);
            System.out.print(root.data + " ");
            printInorder(root.right);
        }
```